# Sap Hana SQL: match a concatenated value with partial match

Tags: sql, hana

I need to write in 1 query a query that gives results below:

```
Table: ldis
MATNR | LDIS
123   | ldi1;ldi2;ldi3
124   | ldi1;ldi2;ldi4
125   | ldi1;ldi3;ldi4
126   | ldi2
127   | ldi

Table: labels
VALUE | LABEL
ldi1 | first label
ldi2 | second label
ldi3 | third label
ldi4 | fourth label
ldi  | otherlabel
```

Query should fetch all MATNR that have an LDI where the labels is containing "second"
(so result should return MATNR 123,124 & 126)

I got this at the moment, but my query only results 126 as matnr:

```
SELECT MATNR
FROM ldis
WHERE 
    (exists 
        (SELECT "VALUE"
        FROM labels
        WHERE 
            LABEL LIKE 'second%' 
        AND 
            "VALUE" LIKE '%'||ldis.LDIS||'%'))
```

I tried to flip it around, but then I get to many results, as the ldi matches to many labels.

```
SELECT MATNR
FROM ldis
WHERE 
    (exists 
        (SELECT "VALUE"
        FROM labels
        WHERE 
            LABEL LIKE 'second%' 
        AND 
            ldis.LDIS LIKE '%'||"VALUE"||'%'))
```

Comment: Fix you data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single string column.

Answer (score 0):

Following may work for you Koen

---

[image]
[image]

SELECT [MATNR]
,SUBSTRING(LDIS,0,5) firstvalue
,SUBSTRING(LDIS,6,9) secondvalue
,SUBSTRING(LDIS,10,15) thirdvalue
FROM [dbo].[idis] xx
where SUBSTRING(LDIS,0,5) in ( (select a.[value] from [dbo].[Labels] a where SUBSTRING(xx.LDIS,0,5) = a.[value] and a.[lable] like '%second%' ))--firstvalue
or
SUBSTRING(LDIS,6,9) in (select b.[value] from [dbo].[Labels] b where SUBSTRING(xx.LDIS,6,9) = b.[value] and b.[lable] like '%second%')-- second value
or
SUBSTRING(LDIS,10,15) in (select c.[value] from [dbo].[Labels] c where SUBSTRING(xx.LDIS,10,15) = c.[value] and c.[lable] like '%second%')

---

[image: Snapshot]